# CSS button pushed down and kept down

Tags: jquery, css, button

Is there any way of keeping a button pushed down, maybe using javascript or jquery?

I would like the button to stay red when clicked on, and this is what I have:

```
<style>
#button {
border: 3px solid #52A7D3;
background-color: #52A7D3;
color: #000000;
}

#button:active {
border: 3px solid red;
background-color: red;
color: #FFF;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<button id="someId">test</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#someId").click(function() {$(this).toggleClass( "active")})
</script>

<style>
#someId{
border: 3px solid #52A7D3;
background-color: #52A7D3;
color: #000000;
}

#someId.active {
border: 3px solid red;
background-color: red;
color: #FFF;
</style>
```

Here is an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zpEVN/)

Comment: is there any way of keeping it red rather than be able to toggle back to blue?

Comment: yes, replace `$(this).toggleClass( "active")` by `$(this).addClass( "active" )`

Answer (score 0):

You should have to follow the below process:

Write a class in CSS file instead of #button:active i.e.

```
.active {border:3px solid red; background-color: red;color: #FFF; }
```

and in your mark up page put the below jquery code in script block

```
$(function(){
   $("#button").mousedown(function(){
       $("#button").addClass("active");
   }).mouseup(function(){
       $("#button").removeClass("active");
   });
});
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hidden checkbox and a label if I were you.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/22h3M/